# Express NodeJS Como tener una ruta que se ejecute siempre que se acceda a cualquier ruta de la app web

Tags: json, nodejs, express, router

Por ejemplo tengo esto:

```
/
   ../herbivoros
                 ../dosPatas
                 ../cuatroPatas

   ../carnivoros
                 ../dosPatas
                 ../cuatroPatas
```

Cada ruta tiene su **routing** correspondiente, un ejemplo:

Para acceder a **herbivoros de pos patas** pues tengo el siguiente **Routing**:

```
app.get('/herbivoros/dosPatas', animales.obtenerHerbivorosDosPatas());
```

y para los **carnivoros de cuatro patas** algo como:

```
animales.get('/carnivoros/cuatroPatas', animales.obtenerHerbivorosCuatroPatas());
```

Ahora bien, si yo quiero que, sea la ruta que sea pase ciertos parametros en formato **json** por ejemplo:

```
res.json({

'color_fondo':'cyan',
'tamañoLetra':19,
'color_h1': 'yellow',
 etc....

});
```

Imagino que no tengo que estar metiendo ese **res** dentro de cada controlador de animales no?

Basicamente lo quiero para tener siempre datos guardados de un **menubar.ejs** que va aestar presente en todas las rutas ya que es una constante en las vistas.

---

Pregunta reformulada:

Estoy usando un **template.ejs** para tener incluido el **menubar** en todas las vistas, que pasa? que el menubar depende de ciertas variables para trabajar correctamente, ya que hay un apartado que se llama **personajes** y no esta hardcodeado sino que esta compuesto por una lista que la lee desde una variable llamada `personajes` por tanto me dice que personaje es `undefined` porque no logro pasarle el objeto **todas las rutas** ya que el objeto el **menu** esta visible en todas las vistas.

Mas facil aun, quiero que el menu lleve una **mochilita** con datos que le interese **independientemente** en la vista que este para que **funcione bien**

Espero asi aclarar mas mi pregunta. Disculpen

Estoy intentado algo como:

```
//middleware

routes.get('*',(req,res,next)=>{

    Personaje.find()
    .then(personajes => {
      res.send({
        personajes:personajes
      })
    })
    console.log('hola mundo')
    next();
})
```

Para que en mi **vista** pueda leer las **variables** :

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">Inicio</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
          <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
              <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                Personajes
              </a>
              <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">

                <% for(var i = 0; i< personajes.length; i++) { %>
                 <a class="dropdown-item" href="personajes">Personaje:  <%= personajes[i].nombre %></a>
                <% } %>

            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </nav>
```

La **session** , dentro de **app.js** lo tengo de la siguiente manera :

```
const session = require('express-session');

//Express-session

app.use(session({
    secret: 'keyboard cat',
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: true
    }));
```

Answer (score 1):

Podrías agregar una declaración de ruteo antes de las que indicas, de forma tal que por medio del patrón de diseño de middlewares que maneja express, sea ejecutada previamente cualquier petición con el verbo get y continué con la siguiente acción.

```
app.get('*', (req, res, next) => {
    res.json({
    'color_fondo':'cyan',
    'tamañoLetra':19,
    'color_h1': 'yellow',
    etc...
    });

    next()
})
```

Comment: en realidad lo quiero para un template de menu.ejs que le quiero pasar un objeto que necesito que este siempre activo para que el menu pueda leer esas variables, le quiero pasar un array de objeto para recorrerlo y tener siempre esos datos. Me pregunto si es la forma correcta de hacerlo

Comment: Me sigue dando el mismo error de que no conoce la variable con la que debe hacer cosas

Comment: la verdad no logro comprender lo que deseas hacer según lo que dices en los comentarios, creo que debes reformular tu pregunta, a que error te refieres?

Comment: Actualizada la cuestion, disculpa.

Comment: haz intentado usar req.session para almacenar la información que necesitas mantener durante la petición?

Comment: no, tampoco lo he conseguido con eso

Comment: mira si aporta algo mas lo que acabo de añadir @nauseantparrot

Comment: veo un problema relacionado al res.send, ya que ello envia la respuesta al cliente, y entonces quedaria incompleto, por que haria falta lo del middleware que corresponde a la peticion propiamente dicha, osea lo de /herbivoros/dosPatas y /carnivoros/cuatroPatas

Comment: podrías mostrar de que forma configuras la sesion, para que puedas almacenar los datos en req.session, y cuando vayas a hacer el res.send del middleware correspondiente, por medio de un spread operator unas el objeto a enviar

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/91784/discussion-between-josanangel-and-nauseantparrot).

Comment: @josanangel recuerda postear la solución, quizá a alguien le sirva después